# How to hide nested attributes in Swagger-ui only for certain response?

Tags: java, serialization, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a class with attributes as below.

```
Class AnimalResponse {

@JsonProperty("animals")
private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonProperty("someOtherAttributes")
private List<someOtherAttribute> someOtherAttributes= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

`Animal.class` looks like below:

```
Class Animal {

@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("height")
private float height;
}
```

I do not want to serialize the attribute `height` inside `Animal.class`.

So, I do the following 2 steps:

1. I create a mixIn ignoring height

   public interface HeightIgnoreMixIn {

   ```
        @JsonIgnore
        String getHeight();
   ```

   }
2. During serialization, I add this mixin.

   new ObjectMapper()
   .addMixIn(Animal.class, HeightIgnoreMixIn .class)
   .writer()
   .writeValueAsString(object);

This works perfectly.

```
**Note: Animal.class is used by other classes.**
```

I do not want to show this `height` in Swagger UI as well. How do I do this?

I can't add `@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)` to `height` because `Animal.class` is used by other classes and they want it visible in the Swagger UI. So, I only want to remove it from the `AnimalResponse` in Swagger UI. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create two different `DTO` classes. One with a `height` field, the second without a `height` field.

This is because with one class swagger uses will use one link twice - you can see this by expanding the "Models" block at the bottom of the swagger UI page.

Comment: Thank you. I have thought about this. But I the problem is, I have many attributes and would need to create mappers if I use two DTO classes. I wanted to avoid this. 

I thought we could somehow annotate the hidden fields  which are nested. Anyway, seems like this is the only solution. Thank you.

Comment: @PH try use `mapstruct` for creating mappers